# SQL Server Delete - Ran out of disk space

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am deleting 257 million rows out of a table in SQL Server 2008. I can't truncate it. I probably could have done it smarter though.

2 hours into the delete, the log file grew and I am out of disk space. The query is still running.

What should I do? Will the delete succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait for the tx to roll back, the delete will not succeed. Or load a backup - could be faster.

Either delete in increments (10.000 at a time) or make sure your server is adequate to handle your needs. All that CAN be done there.

Answer (score 3):

How many records do you need to retain in the table compared to 257 million deletes? If that number is smaller then insert those records in batches to a new table, switch the tables around using ALTER TABLE SWITCH and drop the older table.

http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2009/12/sql-server-2005-how-to-move-10-millions.html

Another interesting idea is to setup partitioning and drop the older partitions.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2010/06/01/purging-data.aspx